# Best hyperchaotic systems

Tags: physics

I need two hyper chaotic systems for my project.could anyone help me for choosing best systems.I was told that hyperchaotic lorenz system  is best. is it true? what about another best system?

Comment: I removed your matlab tag, since the question has nothing to do with matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lorenz system is not a hyperchaos as far as I understand. I don't know what you mean by "best", but you can find a few examples here: http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Hyperchaos